# Simplify bitwise operation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, simplify

I've a `if` statement like this:

```
if ((x & y) == y && (x & z) == 0) { /* do something... */}
```

Is possible to simplify this `if` statement removing the `&&` operator and using *only* bitwise operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short equivalent expression is

```
(x & (y ^ z)) == y
```

which is probably easiest to see correct by looking at all 8 results for a single bit (this is sufficient since the result for each bit is independent of all other bits).